# Undefined Offset Error with simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an XML File called 'groups.xml' and I want to create a child of a child.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <group_no>2</group_no>
  <group id="1">
    <name>Admins</name>
    <backend>1</backend>
    <supplierungen>all</supplierungen>
  </group>
  <group id="2">
    <name>1AFW</name>
    <backend>0</backend>
    <supplierungen>1AFW</supplierungen>
  </group>
</body>
```

First I create the child called "group". It works without any problems, but if I create the child "name" I get following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HLW\functions\cr_gr.php

Here's the code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("../xml/groups.xml");
$res = $xml->xpath("/body");
$no_gr = $res[0]->group_no; 
$res[0]->group_no = $no_gr+1;
$res[0]->addChild("group id=".$res[0]->group_no."");
$res2 = $xml->xpath("/body/group[@id=".$res[0]->group_no."]");
$res2[0]->addChild("name",$_GET['name']);
```

Comment: Quick tip when posting code - no need for `<code>, <br/>` tags. Instead, highlight  code and click `{}` in the editor, or `ctl-k` to indent it 4 spaces as a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're adding of the child seems a little odd.  I would suggest doing it in the following manner:

```
$res = $xml->xpath("/body");
$no_gr = $res[0]->group_no; 
$res[0]->group_no = $no_gr+1;

$child = $res[0]->addChild("group");
$child->addAttribute($id, $res[0]->group_no);
$child->addChild("name", $_GET['name']);
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.addchild.php):

> The `SimpleXMLElement::addChild` method returns a `SimpleXMLElement` object representing the child added to the XML node.

From that return value, you can add all of the attributes and children to the node that you need.